# Android Virtual Device: Accessing NanoHTTPD from hostsystem

Tags: java, android, networking, nanohttpd

I used NanoHTTPD for my android application.

During the development I am running the app on an AVD. Is there a way to accessing the web service from my host system? What´s the IP address of the AVD?

Comment: No. Not easily. You better take a normal device.

Answer (score 1):

Use [adb forward](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#forwardports).

For example, if your NanoHTTPD listens to port 80 on AVD, run

```
adb forward tcp:20001 tcp:80
```

then you can connect to `localhost:20001` on the host machine to access the server.

Comment: thnx, that's worked